# Alternative to Facebook Messenger overlay

Tags: facebook-messenger

It seems Facebook is forcing users to install Facebook Messenger in order to view their messages. Is there a way around this or an alternative? I really hate how with the app messages popup in front of the screen and you have to drag them to the trash can.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the message overlay for Facebook Messenger quite easily.  Hit the Settings (cog) button in the top right of the app, then `Chat heads`, and turn it off.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative Facebook messenger app I heard about is [Fast Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.fastfacebook.com).
If you don't like Fast Facebook you could try [Friend Caster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.senab.blueNotifyFree).